# 300 GB of photos and videos suddenly deleted from external SSD (Samsung T5)

Tags: mac, mojave

Yesterday, somehow over 300 gb of photos, videos and audio disappeared from my Samsung 1TB T5. As a photographer this could have been the end of my career, but luckily I had everything backed up to another Hdd. I will describe what happened:

As usual, the external drive was plugged in, and I was working on my wordpress website, sometimes fetching photos from the ext drive, but I was mostly writing text. I didn't notice anything until  later in the evening, when I was going to fetch one photo and Adobe Lightroom said it couldn't locate the file. I looked in the folder through finder and saw that all the photos in the folder was gone. I looked through some other neighbouring folders and the photos were also gone.

I systematically went through my ext drive and I noticed that between the time 18:38 and 18:41, over 300 gb files of jpg, svg, psd, png, bmp, avi, mp3 were lost. It looks like it started with the oldest files from year 2005 and for some reason stopped at the date 16 sep 2018, at 18:41. For what I can see no documents, zip etc were affected. Also some photos between these dates were spared. So the way files were deleted it must be impossible to manually accidentally delete them. To me it looks like some program has systematically deleted files after filetype and date.

I have had the ext drive plugged in during the day monitoring it, seeing if more files start disappearing but, since 18:41 yesterday, nothing has happened.

I downloaded TotalAV and ran a scan without finding any malware or virus.

I don't need help restoring anything, as I said, everything is backed up, but I need to understand what happened to prevent it from happening again!

My question is, what happened yesterday between 18:38 and 18:41?

MacBook Pro 13" 2017
MacOs Mojave V.10.14.6

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Luckily you had a backup of your photos and videos. Does your Samsung T5 drive have now 300 GB of addtional free disk space (if that's not the case, I'd tend to think the files were moved elsewhere on disk)? Is there a "photo /video library" in Adobe Lightroom (similar to the macOS built-in app Photos), and could something have triggered a mass import?

Comment: Does your Samsung T5 drive have now 300 GB of addtional free disk space? Yes it does.

Comment: Do you use iCloud?

Comment: Do you use iCloud? No.

Comment: Do you know the names of some of the files and if you do, try searching for them? I had something similar happen to me... it was because while selecting multiple files for moving to another directory I had selected a folder by mistake. The folder that I thought was gone was really somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but this is just not possible since 300 GB is now available on the external drive and my internal SSD is smaller than 300 GB, the files haven't been moved. And besides since there are thousands of files that have been affected many of which are on different places on the SSD, you can't accidentally do anything to them all without noticing it. Besides all the folders are still there, just empty.

Comment: I'm intrigued how you know that the files were lost between those two exact times.

Comment: It's a fair question benwiggy, and I should have included that information in the original post. The folders where the affected files were in, were not deleted, so by looking at the "last modified" time I could se when the folders were changed.